# How do I save settings in C#

Tags: c#, settings, preferences

I am building a stand alone program so there are no external files for the program to access. What would be the best way to recall what the size of the window, and the location of a certain element inside the window were prior the the last shut down?

Comment: Beware the .NET Settings mechanism: I remember breaking my application several times on startup, only to find that it was executing code for retrieving the settings, which means that you might see longer startups in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the options are two:

- Also if you're not using external files you could store your settings in the auto-generated .config file;
- Save the values in the registry;

For the first option look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx), for the second try to look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzb96fk.aspx).

**EDIT:** How to write into the registry:

```
RegistryKey currentUser = Registry.CurrentUser;
RegistryKey subKey = currentUser.CreateSubKey("MyTest", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
subKey.SetValue("WindowHeight", 1024);
subKey.SetValue("WindowWidth", 1024);
```

Comment: I prefer to use the registry, I am trying to keep it a stand alone exe. The only thing I can't seem to find, is how do I write deeper into the registry? Your tutorial and all the other I am finding only write to "HKEY_Current_User". How do I write to, say "HKEY_Current_User\Software"?

Comment: Updated my post, see the example :)

Comment: I mean how do I dive deeper into the registry? Like if I wanted to write to "HKEY_Current_User\Software\companyname\program\newkey" How do I do this?

Comment: If your target is to write a portable app then writing to the registry isnt exactly clean/efficient. I would recommend using the Application.Settings class or writing and parsing a simple INI file as described here: http://bytes.com/topic/net/insights/797169-reading-parsing-ini-file-c Good Luck.

Comment: Just use backslash in CreateSubKey method. For example currentUser.CreateSubKey("MyTest\\A\\B\\C\\D\\E", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree) will automagically dive deeper into the registry creating new subkeys if necessary.

Comment: Just wondering, is the CreateSubKey value case sensitive? is CreateSubKey("MyTest\\A") the same as CreateSubKey("mytest\\a")?

Comment: As much as the advice might be correct there is no good reason to write to the registry anymore..

Comment: Why have you downvoted? I've suggested two ways, I haven't said that using the registry is the better option. Read at the first comment of this answer: it's the user that asks how to write into the registry and I've provided a way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

The built in Settings mechanism: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with Settings provided by .NET, that's quiet comfortable:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx